# IE text align property bug

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to make the title image align to left. The image align to left in FF and chrome but stay in center in IE. I have searched internet and it appears this is an IE bug. I was wondering if anyone here can help me about it. Thanks a lot.

HTML

```
<header>
<div id='title'>
<img src='images/title.png'>  //I want this image align to left in IE
</div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header #title{

    text-align:left;

    }
```

Comment: i think `<header>` is not supported by IE it's HTML5 tag

Comment: Just "not working" doesn't say much... What happens? How does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: @Guffa, My bad, the title.png won't align to left and stay in center in IE.

Comment: @mgraph you are right. Are there any ways to walk around this beside removing <header> tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think `<header>` is not supported by IE it's HTML5 tag, so in your css just do this:

```
#title{
    text-align:left;
    }
```

no need to add `header` **id** are unique